# How to add a string above these buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have buttons going from A-Z. I have the jQuery code below where if there are 7 buttons, then display a new row. So it looks like this below:

```
A B C D E F G
H I J K L M N
O P Q R S T U
V W X Y Z
```

But something I just can't get round is that I just want to add a simple word `<p>Answer:</p>` into the top of the buttons so it displays it like this:

Answer:

```
A B C D E F G
H I J K L M N
O P Q R S T U
V W X Y Z
```

I just can't get my head around it, how can I achieve this with my current jQuery code:

```
var $this, i=0, $row, $cell;
$('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if(i%7 == 0) {
        $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
        $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);
    }

    var $newBtn = $("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this);' />".replace('%s',$this.is(':visible')?'inline-block':'none')).attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class'));

    $newBtn.appendTo($cell);

    i++;
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Why don't you set the string in your HTML code?

Comment: I  can't do it in html, trust me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second line ...

`$('#optionAndAnswer .answers').each(function() {`

... to ...

`$('#optionAndAnswer .answers').prepend('<p>Answer:</p>').each(function() {`

Comment: I have tried this but it hasn't worked, it doesn't show "Answer".

Comment: Hm, works for me. What do you mean by "doesn't show"? Is it there if you "view source"? Do you get an error message on the console?

Comment: There is nothing in error console. It displays `$('#optionAndAnswer .answers').prepend('<p>Answer:</p>').each(function() {` in view page source but on the page itself on the browser, it does not display the string "Answer"